# Openpyxl save all content from Excel to list

Tags: python, excel, list, openpyxl

I have written this code to save the content of a XLS file to a list in Python:

```
import xlrd
file = "oktober-results.xls"
content = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
sheet = content.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet_to_list = []
for row in range (sheet.nrows):
    sheet_to_list.append([])
    for col in range (sheet.ncols):
        sheet_to_list[row].append(sheet.cell_value(row, col))
```

This code works well. Recently I was forced to switch my Excel file to XLSX format because this can deal with more lines.

The xlrd module can't handle .xlsx files, I decided to use openpyxl instead.

Now I'm trying to save the content of a xlsx file to a list in Python, but I'm facing trouble:

```
file = "november-results.xlsx"
content = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
sheet = content.active
sheet_to_list = []
for rij in range (1, sheet.max_row +1):
    sheet_to_list.append([])
    for kol in range (1, sheet.max_column +1):
        sheet_to_list[rij].append(sheet.cell(row=rij, column=kol)).value
```

Anyone can help me?

It got the next error:

> sheet_to_list[rij].append(sheet.cell(row=rij, column=kol)).value

> IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

list index starts from 0 the variable "rij" starting value is 1 so when you try to append the list that has only one item that is indexed at 0 it gives you IndexError. you should do like so:

```
sheet_to_list[rij-1].append(sheet.cell(row=rij, column=kol).value)
```

Comment: Hi Mahmumd, it seems to be working now thx. Unfortunately it takes a while to put all the data from the Excel file into my list. Can I use multiprocessing or threading to make this faster?

Comment: Hello, I'm glad its working. Unfortunately I'm not well versed in multiprocessing or threading so I can't help you with that. Good luck on your endeavours!